# __lzcnt returns 31 - (# of leading zeros)

Tags: visual-studio, intrinsics

I am running on 64 bit windows 7, with VS 2015.  Contrary to the documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384809.aspx

__lzcnt() is returning 31 - (leading zero count).

i.e.
__lzcnt(2) = 1;

Is this a known bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this: The lzcnt instruction doesn't generate an exception if executed on a processor that doesn't support it. Instead, the processor sees the lzcnt encoding as BSR (bit scan reverse) proceeded by an ignored prefix value of F3. So your code executes BSR on some processors and LZCNT on others. The solution is to confirm at runtime that the processor really supports the LZCNT instruction.

Comment: I see. So, my results are consistent with a processor that doesn't support LZCNT (< Haswell ).  Thanks!